# How to read dbf file with encoding cp850 in R?

Tags: r, encoding, dbf

I'm trying to load multiple dbf files using RStudio.
The dbf files are saved with encoding cp850.

How can I read dbf files in R with this encoding? I tried but I got the error unsued argument.

```
read.dbf("X:/Users/name/folder1/Routes.dbf", fileEncoding = "cp850")
```

What is the correct way to use this in R? How can I load dbf file with encoding cp850 into RStudio?

Comment: This is from the ‘foreign’ package? That function does not have a `fileEncoding` argument.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, that's right.. however I can't find any example how to load dbf files that are saved with encoding cp805 into RStudio. How can I specify the encoding type when read dbf? :/